# L1-regularization for convex functions

Tags: convex-optimization, regularization

I want to find sufficient conditions such that for a convex function $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, finding the best $x$ with $\lvert\lvert x \rvert\rvert_1 \leq \delta$ is equivalent to using L1-regularization :

$$
\inf_{\lvert\lvert  x \rvert\rvert_1 \leq \delta} f(x) = \inf_{x} f(x)+\lambda \lvert\lvert x \rvert\rvert_1 \qquad\qquad (1)
$$

- Are there such conditions?
- Are there any (standard) references that describe them?

---

#### What I tried so far:

From [Slater's condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater%27s_condition), I know that:

\begin{align*}
\inf_{\lvert\lvert  x \rvert\rvert_1 \leq \delta} f(x) &= \inf_{\lvert\lvert  x \rvert\rvert_1 - \delta \leq 0} f(x) \\
&= \sup_{\lambda \geq 0} \inf_x f(x)+\lambda\Big(\lvert\lvert x\rvert\rvert_1-\delta\Big)
\end{align*}

However, I don't really know how to continue from here.

Comment: @user550103 Yes, I did look into KKT conditions, but I did not see how to leverage them to prove (1)...

Comment: when you arrive at $\max_{\lambda \geq 0} \inf_x f(x)+\lambda\Big(\lvert\lvert x\rvert\rvert_1-\delta\Big)$ you are done

Comment: @LinAlg do you mean because $\max_{\lambda \geq 0} \inf_x f(x)+\lambda\Big(\lvert\lvert x\rvert\rvert_1-\delta\Big) = \min_{x} f(x)+\lambda \lvert\lvert x \rvert\rvert_1$? If so, why?

Comment: @Peter you can fix $\lambda$ to the value for which the maximum is attained. So your actual question is about min vs inf, right?

Comment: Oh, I see. Actually, this totally answers my question. I just did not see it... Thanks a lot! The `min` vs `inf` is not so relevant for me, I could also phrase (1) in terms of only `inf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Slater's condition and convexity, you know that strong duality holds:
\begin{align*}
\inf_{\lvert\lvert  x \rvert\rvert_1 \leq \delta} f(x) &= \inf_{\lvert\lvert  x \rvert\rvert_1 - \delta \leq 0} f(x) \\
&= \sup_{\lambda \geq 0} \inf_x f(x)+\lambda\Big(\lvert\lvert x\rvert\rvert_1-\delta\Big) \\
&= \sup_{\lambda \geq 0} g(\lambda),
\end{align*}
with
$$g(\lambda)=\inf_x f(x)+\lambda\Big(\lvert\lvert x\rvert\rvert_1-\delta\Big).$$
If the primal has an optimal solution $x^*$ (so there is a minum and not just an infimum), then the dual also has an optimal solution $\lambda^*$, so:
$$\inf_{\lvert\lvert  x \rvert\rvert_1 \leq \delta} f(x) = g(\lambda^*).$$
Therefore, the primal has the same objective value as
$$\inf_x f(x)+\lambda^*\Big(\lvert\lvert x\rvert\rvert_1-\delta\Big),$$
where $\lambda^*$ is an optimal solution to the dual problem.